# How can I get all dates of current month till current date?

Tags: php

How can I get list of dates of the current month till current date of that month?The Code I have tried so far. I am getting all the dates of this current month.

```
$month = 12;
$year = 2022;
```

```
   for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
            {
                $time = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year); 

                if (date('m', $time) == $month)  

                    $list[]=date('Y-m-d', $time);
            }
```

Comment: Why not simply test each time whether the date equals the current date? And if so, end the loop. It's unclear if you've actually tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to compare anything. It's sufficient to generate a range of days from 1 until today (if current year/month), or the end of the month (custom year/month), and then then iterate over it, appending days (zero-padded) to the `Y-m-` base date. As follows:

```
/* If for current year/month */
$base = date('Y-m'); // Current base date
$days = range(1,  date('d')); // Days from 1 to now

/* If for other year/month */
// $base = '1980-02'; // Literal base date
// $days = range(1,  date('t', strtotime($base))); // Days from 1 to  month max

/* Combine with day added */
$dates = array_map(function($day) use ($base) {
    return $base . '-' . str_pad((string) $day, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, $days);
```

If generating dates for *this year/month*, use the `$base = date('Y-m');` date call . For *other year/month*, use the literal `$base = '1980-02';` and generate the day range to match the days in that month. With `date('t')` to get "days in month", leap years are considered.

The first option produces (as of today) the following array:

```
[
  0 => '2022-12-01',
  1 => '2022-12-02',
  2 => '2022-12-03',
  3 => '2022-12-04',
  4 => '2022-12-05',
  5 => '2022-12-06',
  6 => '2022-12-07',
  7 => '2022-12-08',
  8 => '2022-12-09',
  9 => '2022-12-10',
  10 => '2022-12-11',
  11 => '2022-12-12',
  12 => '2022-12-13',
  13 => '2022-12-14',
  14 => '2022-12-15',
]
```

Note the `str_pad((string) $day` in padding days, where we typecast the `$day` number to a string. Why? We are iterating integers, while `str_pad()` expects a string. If the argument is not a string, a `TypeError` will be thrown when coding with `declare(strict_types=1)` on.

---

**The above wrapped in a function to make this convenient.** See [Demo](https://3v4l.org/TrTPs#v8.2.0), [Source](https://bitbucket.org/cmswares/stack_overflow/src/master/functions/func.get_dates_in_month.php).

```
/**
 *  Get Dates In Month.
 *  
 *  @updated 2022-12-15 19:09:31 +07:00
 *
 *  @param bool|string  $yearmonth
 *                      true = current year/month
 *                      string = other year/month
 *  
 *  @note If using PHP <8, remove the bool|string union type signature!
 *  @source https://bitbucket.org/cmswares/stack_overflow/src/master/functions/func.get_dates_in_month.php
 *  
 *  @return array
 */

function get_dates_in_month(bool|string $yearmonth): array
{   
    /* If for current year/month */
    if($yearmonth === true) {
        $base = date('Y-m'); // Current base date
        $days = range(1,  date('d')); // Days from 1 to now
    } 
    /* If for other year/month */
    else {
        $base = $yearmonth; // Literal base date
        $days = range(1,  date('t', strtotime($yearmonth))); // Days from 1 to  month max
    }

    /* Combine with day added */
    $dates = array_map(function($day) use ($base) {
        return $base . '-' . str_pad((string) $day, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, $days);
    return $dates;
}

echo "==== Current Y/M ====\n";
var_dump(get_dates_in_month(true));

echo "==== Other Y/M ====\n";
var_dump(get_dates_in_month('1980-02'));
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to accommodate both "current base date" and "custom base date" that generates the date range for any year-month combination. (Using `date('t')` takes into account leap years and gives `29` for e.g. "1980-02".)

Comment: Thanks! Your code works like a charm. But If I want to send different month how can i get all the days of that month? and if i send current month i will get the dates till current date only. And I know I didn't mention that in the question,later I realize that

Comment: @Display I have given that option in the answer. Just use the /* If for other year/month */ variables. Answer updated to include a function. Use `true` for current, literal `YYYY-mm` for other. See [demo](https://3v4l.org/TrTPs#v8.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

This answer works for OP's original question ("current month") not for the edited question.

```php
$list = [];

$now_day = intval(date('d'));

for($d=1; $d<=$now_day; $d++)
{
    $list[]= date('Y-m-').str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: But it is returning dates till todays date for every month I select. Like If i select January I am getting dates till 15th jan. But I want to get all the dates of january but for current month I want till current date.

Comment: @Display That's not what you asked for...

Comment: "dates of the current month till current date" and what you're telling me now it's something different. Plase edit your Question or make another one

Comment: Ok . Sorry my bad

Comment: This answer works for OP's original question ("current month"). Will obviously not work for generating dates in another month. Prepending a date stem, set before the loop, to a zero-padded day is the "economic" approach. Might want to set `$list = [];` before the loop.

Comment: I edited the answer in order to avoid ambiguities and thanks @MarkusAO about the init of the list i didn't inserted in my answer because actually i don't know if it should be empty in that snippet or not so i focused on the logic part.

Answer (score 1):

This also should work.

```
$date = '2022-12-01'; //you can choose any date here
$end = '2022-12-' . date('t', strtotime($date));

while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
    $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
    $day_month = date('m', strtotime($date));
    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
    $day_year = date('y', strtotime($date));
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    echo "{$day_name} {$day_num} {$day_month} {$day_year}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$dates = [];
for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++)
{
    $date = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if(strtotime($date) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) {
        break;
    }
    $dates[] = $date;
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: This works, however it's a heck of a lot of function calls for each iteration. You could evaluate `date('Y')`, `date('m')` and `strtotime(date('Y-m-d')` up front before the loop, since they won't change, to save up to 90 redundant function calls at the end of the month.